# File operations. A c program that will take a single command line argument using fork() execvp() , wait/waitpid()

Tags: c, shell

I was writing a program that could pass in a command-line argument in c program. The linux command are stored in a file called "sample-input". It only contains cp file1 dest1 or mv file2 dest2. My problem is when I tokenize the string in the file. It seems like it only reading the first line of the file. Here is my code. Can someone help me, please?

```
error message i got (after edit):

    temp1/f4.txt
 temp1/f5.txt
 temp1/f6.txt
-temp1/f7.c
+temp1/f8.c
+temp2/f1.txt
 temp2/f2.c
+temp2/f3.txt
 temp2/f4.txt
+temp2/f5.txt
 temp2/f6.txt
 temp2/f9.c
Test Result: [Failed]


    my sample-input
    cp temp1/f1.txt              temp2/
    mv temp1/f2.c                           temp2/
    cp temp1/f3.txt                temp2/
    cp temp1/f4.txt                temp2/
    cp temp1/f5.txt                temp2/
    cp temp1/f6.txt                 temp2/
    mv temp1/f7.c                   temp1/f8.c
    mv temp1/f9.c                   temp2/
    cp temp1/f1.txt              temp1/f1a.txt
```

My current code.

```
   /* Your code goes here */

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("sample-input", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "An error has occured1\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "argc=%d\n", argc);
        fprintf(stderr, "An error has occured2 \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (argc == 2) {
        char ag[1024];

        while (fgets(ag, 1024, fp) != NULL)
        {
            fgets(ag, 1024, fp);

            char* array[4];
            int i = 0;
            char* token = strtok(ag, " \t\n");

            while (token != NULL) {

                array[i] = token;
                i++;
                token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
            }
            array[i] = NULL;
            int r = fork();

            if (r == 0) {
                execvp(array[0], array);
            }
            else if (r < 0) {

                fprintf(stderr, "An error an occoured\n");
                exit(1);

            }
            else {

                wait(NULL);

            }


        }




    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
execvp(array[i], array);
```

has to be

```
execvp(array[0], array);
```

because the first argument shall be the filename of the executable. And you should handle the case, that `execvp()` fails, properly by issuing a message and exiting (!).

```
perror("execvp");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Furthermore, you have to NULL-terminate your argument vector by setting

```
array[i] = NULL;
```

after your while-loop. And better add a check, that breaks out of the loop after parsing three arguments, otherwise `array` can overflow (write out of bounds leading to undefined behaviour).

Another problem is your read-loop

```
while (fgets(ag, 1024, fp) != NULL) {
        fgets(ag, 1024, fp);
}
```

This will somewhat read your file wildly and leave you with the last or previous-last line. You have to put the line handling *inside* the loop:

```
while (fgets(ag, 1024, fp) != NULL) {
    // Parse arguments and fork/exec here inside
}
```

According to your input file, it looks like tabulators might also be an argument separator, so use

```
strtok(ag, " \t\n");
```

and

```
strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
```

Comment: after editing my program still gives me the same error. It looks like the file wasn't copied and moved to the destination folder. Could you take a look at that?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you edit the messages you get into your question, please? Properly formatted, preferably

Comment: @DeZeng Maybe tabulators are the problem, see the updated answer

Comment: I keep checking the temp2 file but seem like nothing has been moved to it.

Comment: Please make sure, that you addressed _all_ issues I raised above. If you have, then please add your current code in your question _in addition_ to the original one (do not remove this one)

Comment: @DeZeng You did not address the issue with the loop, do this first.

Comment: Sorry. Do you mean I should put all the fork() and tokenize inside the while loop of reading file?

Comment: @DeZeng correct, if all commands shall be executed this is necessary

Comment: I just edit my code again and it did move 4 files into temp2. But still not all the files

Comment: @DeZeng Ok, please update the _second_ source in the question with your current code (not the original one at the top please)

Comment: It seems to me it is only doing the even-number line command. second line fourth line and so on

Comment: Please show your current code, but it sounds, like you have _two_ `fgets()`, one in the loop condition and one in the loop body. Remove the one in the body.

Comment: I just update the current code I have now. Thank you again for your patient. It's my first time asking a question in Stack overflow

Comment: As I said, remove the second `fgets()`, then every line should get parsed. Remember, `fgets()` _consumes_ lines, so each line, that is read when evaluating the loop-condition, is lost when you call the `fgets()` inside the loop body

Comment: @DeZeng And everybody like: yay! ;)